# There is a subtle bug in the review queues: The (up to recently) normally greyed-out options are no longer greyed out (yet remain unclickable)

Tags: bug, design, review-tools

The title says it all, really. Normally, when one hasn't done anything the "I'm done" option in the First Post review queue is greyed-out. Now, it is no longer so, but one still cannot click it. Similarly, after having done something, the "No Action Needed" button is not greyed-out, yet unclickable. The same happens in e.g. the Late Answers review queue.

I speculate that this bug was introduced with the new font (I noticed it more than one day, but not much more than that, ago), though I have no evidence to support that claim.

Comment: I've noticed too

Comment: This bug has been fixed (mods, feel free to add a [tag:status-completed] tag).